# Unable to remove documents from Firebase / Firestore, using SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mvvm, swiftui

guys.
I created an application in SwiftUI (MVVM) able to include and update documents in Firebase / Firestore. However, I cannot remove these documents from Firestore. With the approach presented below, I can remove a row from the list. However, the row reappears after an update in the View, as it has not been deleted from the firestore.
Could someone tell me what's wrong with the code below? I believe I'm not correctly passing the documentID through the functions.
Thanks in advance.

Below I present the codes related to onDelete and the function deleteItem, taken from ContentView, FileModel, FileViewModel and FileRepository(Firestore).

In ContentView:

```
@ObservedObject var fileViewModel: FileViewModel

var body: some View {
            VStack {
               List{
                 ForEach (fileViewModel.fileModel) { data in
                   VStack {
                           Text(data.itemOne)
                           Text(data.itemTwo)
                           }
                      }.onDelete(perform: {_ in self.fileViewModel.deleteItem()})
                    }
                  }
                }
```

In FileModel:

```
@DocumentID var id: String?
var itemOne: String
var itemTwo: String
```

In FileViewModel:

```
func deleteItem() {
 FileRepository.deleteItem()
}
```

In FileRepository:

```
 func deleteItem() {
   db.collection("fileModel").document("id").delete() { err in
    if let err = err {
            print("Error removing document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully removed!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the printed console message `Document successfully removed!`, if so it's because you aren't also removing `data.<someItem>` from your local copy. Where it's successfully removed you need to make sure to update your `data` item.

Comment: Also, you can open the Firebase Firestore and watch it live to see if it's actually being deleted. I suspect that it is, you're just not updating locally.

Comment: Do you really just have one document with the `id` `"id"`? That's all that is getting deleted in `deleteItem`. Also, it's surprising to me that you wouldn't pass the index of the of the item in `onDelete`, although I guess that makes sense if there's only one document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [xTwisteDx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12417531/xtwistedx) and [jnpdx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560942/jnpdx) for the help answers.

As mentioned by [jnpdx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560942/jnpdx), and as I was guessing, I needed to pass the item index into onDelete. But for that, it was necessary to create a new ViewModel (rowViewModel), and instantiate it inside fileViewModel, as in the approach presented by [Peter Friese](https://www.peterfriese.net/replicating-reminder-swiftui-firebase-part1/#keeping-tasks-in-a-repository).

In my case, the code is presented bellow.

In ContentView:

```
           List{
             ForEach (fileViewModel.rowViewModel) { data in
               VStack {
                       Text(data.itemOne)
                       Text(data.itemTwo)
                       }
                  }.onDelete { indexSet in self.fileViewModel.deleteItem(atOffsets: indexSet)}
```

In FileModel: the same as above.

In FileViewModel:

```
func deleteItem(atOffsets indexSet: IndexSet) {
    let viewModels = indexSet.lazy.map { self.rowViewModel[$0] }
    viewModels.forEach { rowViewModel in
      fileRepository.removeItem(rowViewModel.row)         }
  }
```

In FileRepository:

```
func removeItem(_ fileModel: FileModel) {
    if let fileModelID = fileModel.id {
    db.collection("fileModels").document(fileModelID).delete() { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error removing document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully removed!")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Again, thanks a lot for all clues.